# Sending complex hash/array trees to rails with jMeter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jmeter

I want the params hash to end up with something fairly complex, like this:

```
{ foo: "a",
  bar: [
    { b: "c", d: "e"}
    { b: "f", d: "g"}
  ]
}
```

From a POST request in jMeter. I've been unable to find relevant documentation. I've been able to pass a version with strings in place of symbols like this:

```
foo=a;bar[][b]=c;bar[][d]=e;bar[][b]=f;bar[][d]=g;
```

which gives me:

```
{ "foo" => "a",
  "bar" => [
    { "b"=> "c", "d"=> "e"}
    { "b"=> "f", "d"=> "g"}
  ]
}
```

Close but not what the API needs.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using JSON in the POST request.

I got how to do that from this blog post: http://ppettitau.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/posting-a-json-request-with-jmeter/

Basically, the key thing that is easy to miss is that the headers need to be configured in a separate jMeter object from the actual request.